# Transparent Ellipse

Tags: c++, gdi, geometry, drawellipse

How do you draw a transparent ellipse with GDI? I tried `SetBkMode()` but I still get a white ellipse bk.

```
case WM_PAINT:
{
    hdc = BeginPaint(hwnd, &ps);
    SetBkMode(hdc, TRANSPARENT); // doesnt work
    Ellipse(hdc, 0,0,500,500);
    EndPaint(hwnd, &ps);
    break;
}
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Borrowed from [Fill an ellipse in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1385819/fill-an-ellipse-in-c):

> The ellipse is outlined by using the current pen and **is filled by using the current brush**.

Therefore, you need to set a transparent brush. For that, use `GetStockObject(HOLLOW_BRUSH)` to obtain it and `SelectObject()` to activate it for a given device context. So your code can be like this:

```
case WM_PAINT:
{
    hdc = BeginPaint(hwnd, &ps);
    SelectObject(hdc, GetStockObject(HOLLOW_BRUSH));
    Ellipse(hdc, 0,0,500,500);
    EndPaint(hwnd, &ps);
    break;
}
```